# jquery - touchend preventDefault if original target was a link/image

Tags: touch, jquery

I'm making my site touch friendly and have put created a simple carousel style plugin which works great, however when the touchend event is fired and the original target was an image (user touches image and then swipes/left to navigate) it's still opening the link associated with image.

I've put in event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault() but it has no effect.

Does anyone have any idea on how to prevent this?

Edit:

I'm binding the touch event using:

```
obj.parent().bind('touchstart', onTouchStart);
obj.parent().bind('touchend', onTouchEnd);
```

Here is the touchend function

```
function onTouchEnd(event) {
    if(!cdata.in_touch) return;
    cdata.in_touch = false;

    var pos = getPointerPosition(event);
    var final_distance = Math.sqrt(pos.x - cdata.touch_start);
    cdata.timer_end = new Date();
    cdata.timer_length = cdata.timer_end - cdata.timer_start;

    if(cdata.timer_length > 100) {
        if (final_distance > 100) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            // no effect, link associated with image still fires
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Does anyone have any idea on how to prevent this?" by posting piece of your code maybe...

Comment: Would it be possible to have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Why don't you bind also click and touchend ?

Comment: Added some more code to original question. Binding click doesn't have any effect unfortunately

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you have an image object and you bind the events to its parent? You need to show html as well. Looks like you are bubbling up already with the event and try to stop the event while it fired already

Answer (score 3):

The general technique for solving this problem is to listen to `touchstart`.  Once `touchstart` is fired, save the touch X-Y coordinates and attach listeners for `touchend` and `touchmove`.  The `touchend` listener should invoke the designated callback you want to call (i.e. show the tapped image in full screen).  The `touchmove` should monitor the distance that was moved from the original tap X-Y coordinates and if it exceeds a certain threshold, it cancels the `touchend` (and also the now redundant `touchmove` event).

There's an excellent article with reference code that does this by Google
https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons

And also, a new Github project by FTlabs called FastClick which is even more comprehensive;
https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick